# RPScreenRecorder How recording screen audio and video of an app Action Extension?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, replaykit, rpscreenrecorder

I would like to record the screen, audio, and video of my app with target **Action Extension**.

If I put this code in a normal app, it works, but in an Action Extension doesn't.

```
@IBAction func recButton(_ sender: Any) {


        if recButton.currentTitle == "stop" {
            stopRecording()
            recButton.setTitle("rec", for: .normal)
        }
        else {

            recButton.setTitle("stop", for: .normal)

            RPScreenRecorder.shared().isMicrophoneEnabled = true
            RPScreenRecorder.shared().startRecording(handler: {[unowned self] (error) in

            //Handler - never called
            if let unwrappedError = error {
                print(unwrappedError.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
        }
    }

    func stopRecording() {
        RPScreenRecorder.shared().stopRecording(handler: {(previewController, error) -> Void in

            //Handler - never called
            if previewController != nil {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Recording", message: "Do you want to discard or view your recording?", preferredStyle: .alert)

                let discardAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Discard", style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in
                    RPScreenRecorder.shared().discardRecording(handler: { () -> Void in
                        // Executed once recording has successfully been discarded
                    })
                }

                let viewAction = UIAlertAction(title: "View", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                    self.present(previewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })

                alertController.addAction(discardAction)
                alertController.addAction(viewAction)

                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            } else {
                // Handle error
            }
        })
    }
```

Is there another method to achieve this goal using AVCaptureSession, or do I need to use something else to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: This question got me really interested in this concept! I'm not sure what you're trying to do sadly, but what you might want to look into is the `Broadcast Extension` target. This might help a little :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure Apple won't let you do that **by design**. When it comes to extensions, they are generally **very strict** both in terms of what is allowed api-wise and what will pass app review.

Even if you figure out a hacky solution to overcome the issues with *ReplayKit*, I guess it would get rejected by app review.

In the general [App Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines), the [app extension programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Action.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH13-SW1) is referenced as a defining guideline where for action extension it specifically says:

> In iOS, an Action extension:
>
> - Helps users view the current document in a different way
> - Always appears in an action sheet or full-screen modal view
> - Receives selected content only if explicitly provided by the host app

Not quite sure how a screen recording would fit into that pattern in a way that convinces Apple...

Comment: Thank to reply. My app "Helps users view the current document in a different way" is like a text reading, now, I just want to record the text read. is possible with AV or other?

Comment: When ReplayKit doesn't work in an app extension, but does in the app itself, I think it's by general design (that extensions can't invoke recording frameworks). So I don't think there is any proposed solution to do this...

Comment: As per my understanding this should be possible. However,  I am not sure how to do that in Message Extension apps. I am working on it and will let you know very soon if able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is not possible, as I have seen some apps on App Store, which are recording video and Audio within iMessage extension app. Like : [SuperMoji App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/supermoji-the-emoji-app/id1300364926?mt=8) This app records face expression and audio 
 and sends as a video message within iPhone's Message app only.

However, I am not sure how to do that in Extension apps. I am working on it and will let you know very soon.